# Iterate over columns in a pandas dataframe and output result into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to iterate over the columns in a pandas dataframe that is 6 x 22 columns using `df.apply(min_max, axis=0)` and get the output in a new dataframe with two columns as below.

```
   def min_max(column):
      column_names = ['column', 'value']
      output = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
      output2 = pd.DataFrame([column, abs(column.max() - column.min())])
      return output.append(output2)
```

df is shown in attached img: [first few columns on current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YI02.png)

Two questions:

1. I'm getting the error below:

   TypeError: ("object of type 'Timedelta' has no len()", 'occurred at index date')
2. Is there a way I can exclude all
   columns that are not `dtype = int`? Does this go into the function?

Much oblidged.

Comment: for error 1: are you passing the date column to the function ?

Comment: @giorgos, I am but I don't want to be. That's what I was asking about with the second question (in my mind at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude = ['int']).apply(min_max, axis = 0)
```

[pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

To select all numeric values use numpy.number.

Comment: This works to reduce the df to the columns that are only int64 which is great. It's now clear the original issue is with the function but I don't see the obvious problem there yet....

Comment: try excluding timedelta @mintgreenstrat